# How to add an add row button React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am a beginner web developer, I have a code for a table on React using JSON data, please tell me how to implement so that "when a button is clicked a new line is created"

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import StaffTable from './components/staff-table'
import data from './data/staff.json'


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       <h1><StaffTable  data={data} /></h1>
      </div>

    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

export default function StaffTable(props) {
    return (
        <div>
        <table>

            <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>age</th>
                    <th>number</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                {
                props.data.map(row =>(
                    <tr>
                        <td>{row.id}</td>
                        <td>{row.name}</td>
                        <td>{row.age}</td>
                        <td>{row.number}</td>
                        <td><button className="editRow">Edit</button></td>
                    </tr>

                ))
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button className="addRow" >State</button>
        </div>
    )

}
```

staff.json

```
[

        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Alex",
            "age": "18",
            "number": "00000"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Anton",
            "age": "20",
            "number": "11111"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Bob",
            "age": "22",
            "number": "22222"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Ivan",
            "age": "25",
            "number": "33333"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Jack",
            "age": "28",
            "number": "44444"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Maria",
            "age": "30",
            "number": "55555"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Viktoria",
            "age": "32",
            "number": "66666"
        }           

]
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to fill the new row with new data. Or do you just want an empty row.

Comment: I would just like to create a string

Comment: See my solution below and let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo it looks like you want to create a new row/person by clicking a button. Naturally, the way we would do that is by creating a new object in the array you are iterating over to create the table. But since you are using props, we will not be able to mutate that specific array.

However, by introducing `state`, we can freely add/edit the data array. Simply just set the initial state value equal to `props.data`.

In the "Add Row" button, we have an event-handler for when the user clicks. We will create a new person object, update the component-state and then iterate over it. Thus we will have a new row that we can edit.

Consider an example like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function StaffTable(props) {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(props.data);

  const createPerson = () => {
    setPeople([
      ...people,
      { id: people.length + 1, name: "", age: "", number: "" }
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>number</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {people.map(row => (
            <tr>
              <td>{row.id}</td>
              <td>{row.name}</td>
              <td>{row.age}</td>
              <td>{row.number}</td>
              <td>
                <button className="editRow">Edit</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={createPerson} className="addRow">
        Add Row
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-pond-6f00j

Ultimately, the code above will not help you create a string. But, by following the same concepts, we can render a form that allows the user to fill-out information for the new person.

See working sandbox and code below: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-butterfly-v7ih1

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function StaffTable(props) {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(props.data);
  const [displayForm, setDisplayForm] = useState(false);
  const [newPerson, setNewPerson] = useState({
    name: "",
    age: "",
    number: ""
  });

  const createPerson = () => {
    setPeople([...people, { id: people.length + 1, ...newPerson }]);
    setNewPerson({ name: "", age: "", number: "" });
    setDisplayForm(false);
  };

  const handleOnChange = e => {
    setNewPerson({
      ...newPerson,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>number</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {people.map(row => (
            <tr>
              <td>{row.id}</td>
              <td>{row.name}</td>
              <td>{row.age}</td>
              <td>{row.number}</td>
              <td>
                <button className="editRow">Edit</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {displayForm ? (
        <div>
          <input
            placeholder="name"
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            value={newPerson.name}
            name="name"
          />
          <input
            placeholder="age"
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            value={newPerson.age}
            name="age"
          />
          <input
            placeholder="number"
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            value={newPerson.number}
            name="number"
          />
          <button onClick={createPerson} className="addRow">
            Create Person
          </button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={() => setDisplayForm(!displayForm)} className="addRow">
          Add Row
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me figure this out.

Comment: @GreenZo awesome! I'm glad this helped you. When you have a chance, please consider upvoting and marking this as the solution (green check button).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a "row" component and a "rows" component. Both of these would be stored in your "app" component. Your "app" component should have an array of data (in it's state) you pass to the "rows" component.

Clicking an add new button would call a function in the app component that adds a row to the array in the app components state.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addNewLine(data,e) {

    data.push({
            "id": data.length+1,
            "name": "",
            "age": "",
            "number": ""
        })
}

export default function StaffTable(props) {
    return (
        <div>
        <table>

            <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>age</th>
                    <th>number</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                {
                props.data.map(row =>(
                    <tr>
                        <td>{row.id}</td>
                        <td>{row.name}</td>
                        <td>{row.age}</td>
                        <td>{row.number}</td>
                        <td><button className="editRow">Edit</button></td>
                    </tr>

                ))
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button className="addRow" onClick=(props.data,e) => {addNewLine(props.data,e)} >add new line</button>
        </div>
    )

}
```